# pandas python sorting according to a pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that consists of 5 columns. The second column has the numbers 1 to 500 repeated 5 times. As a shorter example the second column is something like this `(1,4,2,4,3,1,1,2,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,3)` and I want to sort it to look like this `(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)`. The code i am using to sort is  `df=res.sort([2],ascending=True)` but this code sorts it `(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)`.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have another column with those five different kind of entries since those double? So like A --> 1, A --> 2, A --> 3, A --> 4, ...  A --> 500, B --> 1,  B --> 2, ...  B --> 500, ... , E --> 1, E --> 2, E --> 3, ... , E --> 5. If so, you could use this as a combined index in order to sort the data properly. Please paste a small snippet of your complete dataframe or at least a significant part of it.

Comment: so I have 10-->1,10-->1,10-->1,10-->1, 10-->2,...,10-->2, 10-->3,..,10-->3, 10-->4,..,10-->4, then 20-->1,.......,20-->4, then 30-->1,...30-->4 and so on till 100

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How's about this: [sort](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by the [cumcount](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then the value itself:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame({"s": [1,4,2,4,3,1,1,2,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,3]})

In [12]: df.groupby("s").cumcount()
Out[12]:
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     1
6     2
7     1
8     2
9     1
10    2
11    3
12    3
13    2
14    3
15    3
dtype: int64

In [13]: df["s_cumcounts"] = df.groupby("s").cumcount()

In [14]: df.sort_values(["s_cumcounts", "s"])
Out[14]:
    s  s_cumcounts
0   1            0
2   2            0
4   3            0
1   4            0
5   1            1
7   2            1
9   3            1
3   4            1
6   1            2
10  2            2
13  3            2
8   4            2
11  1            3
14  2            3
15  3            3
12  4            3

In [15]: df = df.sort_values(["s_cumcounts", "s"])

In [16]: del df["s_cumcounts"]
```